# "Nor" used to join two independent clause, but some says it can also join other elements

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, parts-of-speech

**I haven’t seen nor heard from Mike in days.**

I know:- "nor" is used to join two independent clauses, but like above sentence can be used to join two elements that are not independent clauses.

Comment: _Nor_ is used with _neither_ to link two negatives - _I have neither seen nor heard from Mike._ It doesn't matter what part of speech they are. _I have neither a raincoat nor an umbrella with me._

Comment: @Sam "Nor" does not have to be used with "neither", cf. "Serious art is not [for the lazy nor for the untrained]". In your example "or" would be preferable to "nor".